# why a function like this idGetter can not be applied to Map function in java stream api?

Tags: java, stream

```
public <T> List<Long> leafIds(Map<Long, ? extends List<? extends T>> childrenMap, Long parentId, Function<? extends T, Long> idGetter) {
    if (!childrenMap.containsKey(parentId)) {
        return Collections.singletonList(parentId);
    }
    List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> childrenIds = new ArrayList<>();
    childrenIds.add(parentId);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenIds.size(); i++) {
        Long childId = childrenIds.get(i);
        List<? extends T> children = childrenMap.get(childId);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(children)) {
            childrenIds.addAll(children.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(idGetter).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            continue;
        }
        result.add(childId);

    }
    return result;
}
```

[error mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsb5T.png)
there is an error mark under line 12, the editor indicates that type of [idGetter] is wrong,how can I fix this?
I'll be grateful for any help!

Comment: There is PECS principle and your function is a consumer, not a producer, if you change function like that Function<? super T, Long> it will work

Comment: Alexander Ivanchenko and Dmitrii B, thank you very much! I fixed this problem using solution mentioned by Dmitrii B ^_^

Comment: Imagine that `T` type has some subtypes `T1` and `T2`. The `Function<? extends T, Long>` lets us assign to it function like `Function<T2, Long>`. Now imagine that such function was written like `t -> t.methodDeclaredInT2()`. Note that `methodDeclaredInT2` returns Long, but **doesn't exist in T1 nor T** since it was declared only in T2. BUT in your code the `List<? extends T> children = childrenMap.get(childId);` can hold `List<T1>` and/or `List<T>`. This means that function could try to call `methodDeclaredInT2` on instances of T or T1 which don't have such method. See the problem?

Comment: Pshemo,thank you,I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Function<? extends T, Long>` means:

Any function that converts some specific but unknown thing to a Long, where we do know that, whatever it is, it's either `T` or some subtype thereof.

It specifically **does not mean**: "A function that can take any T and convert it to a Long". If you want that, you'd need a `Function<T, Long>`.

`List<? extends T>` means:

A list whose elements are constrained; they must all be `instanceof` some type we don't know. We do know that, whatever type it is, it is at least T or some subtype of T.

It specifically **does not mean**: A list whose elements are constrained to be instanceof T. Because that'd just be a `List<T>`.

The expression `list.get(0)`, if `list` is a `List<T>`, is itself T. Obviously. It's still T if the `list` is a `List<? extends T>` instead. The crucial difference is with `add`: you can call `list.add(someInstanceOfT)` just fine, *if* the type of `list` is `List<T>`. However, `list.add(anything)` doesn't compile if `list`'s type is `List<? extends T>`.

Think about it:

```java
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> numbers = myList;
numbers.add(someDouble);
```

The above **does not compile** - specifically, the third line (`numbers.add`) does not. And now it should be obvious why: The `numbers` variable is pointing at a list whose constraint is unknown. Maybe it is `Integer`, which would mean adding a double to it, is broken.

The key thing to keep in mind is PECS: Produce-Extends-Consume-Super. This is from the point of view of the object: a `list.get()` call "produces" a value, therefore, `extends` bounds are useful (a `List<? extends Number>` can be used for meaningful production, because PE: Produce-Extends: `.get()` call, which produces, gives you `Number`. Or flip it around, CS: a `List<? super Number>` can meaningfully consume: `list.add(someNumber)` is allowed on them. But `list.get(0)` on a `List<? super Number>` is not particularly useful (it gets you an object, because all lists can't store anything else, but nothing more specific).

Now back to functions. The first typearg of a function is **solely used** for *consumption*: The point of that first arg is that your function consumes these. The second argument is **solely used** for *production*.

Thinking about PECS, `Function<? extends Anything, _>` **is completely useless**, given that `extends` means its useful only for production, and the first typearg of `Function` is solely used for consumption.

Java is 'correct', your code is broken. What did you really mean?

Two options:

### Option 1

If you intend to accept a function that can process any T, then it should be either a `Function<T` or a `Function<? super T`, as per PECS rules.

### Option 2

Generics serve to link things, given that they are a figment of the compiler's imagination (`java` the VM doesn't know what they are, and most of the type args are erased entirely by `javac`). Perhaps you intended to link the type used in the first parameter with the type used in that function. Then.. make a type variable for that purpose, that is their job. You've already done that, so, fix up your bounds so they align with PECS:

```
public <T> List<Long> leafIds(Map<Long, ? extends List<? extends T>> childrenMap, Long parentId, Function<? super T, Long> idGetter) {
```

All I did was swap `? extends` to `? super`. What that says is:

There is some specific type. No idea what it is, though. Let's call it T.

The first argument gives us a map that maps to a list of Xs, where X is either that unknown type T or some subtype of that.

The third argument is a mapping function that is capable of converting some unknown type to something else. The unknown type it can convert is, however, guaranteed to be either T or some supertype of it.

That paints a complete, type-wise consistent picture. Let's say the map gives out Integers and the function can convert any Object (so, T is Number, the list are a subtype of T: Integer, check, and the mapping function can convert any Object, that's a supertype of T, so, check). That works out.

Now let's go in reverse:

The lists have Numbers in them, and the mapping function can only convert Doubles.

So what happens if one of the elements in the list is an Integer instead? Type safety broken.

Comment: It's so kind of you to explain where and why I was wrong,I think I've understood the PECS principle after reading your explanation,thank you very much!